# Including Entry Property in Object

Tags: entries, category, plugin-seo

I'm trying to get the category title to render within the following object but it's just returning it as the static string instead of the {{ category.title }} actually rendering.

```
{% set seo = craft.seo.custom(
    'Welcome back, {{ category.title }}',
    'Test Meta Description!'
) %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
{% set seo = craft.seo.custom(
    'Welcome back, ' ~ category.title ~ ', Test Meta Description!'
) %}
```

Or even more clear (to me anyway):

```
{% set seo = craft.seo.custom(
    "Welcome back, #{category.title}, Test Meta Description!"
) %}
```

More here: https://twitter.com/nystudio107/status/938018528527036416?s=21